# QGIS does not find existing column when drawing lines between two point layers

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer

I have two layers containing points. I want to draw lines from each point of layer Quellen to each point of layer Ziele. Layer Quellen has an ID called q.id, Layer Ziele has an ID called z.id.

[image: attribute tables]

I have already found multiple Questions here that somehow solve this problem, using a virtual layer with the query

```
select a.id, b.id, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
from myLayer a, myLayer b
```

which I took and edited to fit my names in two ways already

```
select q.id, z.id, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
from Quellen, Ziele
```

```
select q.id, z.id, makeline(q.geometry, z.geometry) as geometry
from Quellen, Ziele
```

(I was not sure, if a.geometry is a fixed variable or depending on the id name)

But the test of my virtual layer is already failing at finding column "q.id"
[image: error message]

What am I doing wrong here?
I am not sure if I actually need any IDs at all as I want to draw a line from each object of layer Quellen to each object of layer Ziele. IMO that should not depend on any ID. Maybe there is another approach to achieve that?

Comment: it should be something like: "select Quellen.q.id, Ziele.z.id, makeline(Quellen.geometry, Ziele.geometry) as geometry
from Quellen, Ziele" and I would avoid points in your column names

Comment: tried that, now it says "Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such column: Quellen.q.id" its not the points either as i have also already tried qid and zid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You miss the aliases for the layer names (`q` and `z`) and the points in the column names are interfering with the `layer.column` syntax.

Try this:

```
select q."q.id", z."z.id", makeline(q.geometry, z.geometry) as geometry
from Quellen q, Ziele z
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried that, I am still getting the same error (no such column: q.id)

Comment: I got your column names wrong (I missed the `q.` / `z.`), perhaps my edit with the quotation marks works?

Comment: Passed with no errors and works! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Nice. I added a little clarification to my answer for future readers